# Удаление игр из стим в компьютерном клубе

Tags: windows, steam

Я работаю в компьютерном клубе и иногда люди которые играют в компьютерном клубе удаляют игры из стима зайдя в библиотеку **нажав на игру правой кнопкой мыши** а затем нажав на
**Управление - Удалить с устройства**, дота удаляется с диска и чтобы установить её нужно заново **нажать установить** и ждать пока она установиться несколько часов, соответственно падение бренда и огромные убытки. Как можно сделать так чтобы клиент не смог удалить доту с компьютеров.

Comment: Нужно знать подробнее, какая у вас винда. А вообще создавайте учетную запись без права удаления/установки программ. Должно помочь.

Comment: Т.к. стим ставит игры под текущим пользователем, то вряд ли поможет разделение учёток. Но вот ограничение на удаление средствами ntfs - вполне должно прокатить. Чё-то типа этого: https://blue42.net/windows/changing-ntfs-security-permissions-using-powershell/ и https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights

Comment: Здесь: https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/6B1A-66BE-E911-3D98